# android studio intent transition between the activities

Tags: android-studio, android-intent

I have a problem in android studio with intents. I have 3 activity. Assuming that the activities are A B C. Firstly I start A activity and then go B activity and then C activity and then B activity. (A->B->C->B) When I turned B activity from C activity, I press back button and I go C activity but I dont want to go C activity. When I press back button in B activity, I want to go A activity. So What I happened? please help me

Answer (score 0):

you can set your Activity B `launchMode` on `AndroidManifest.xml` to

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityB"
          android:launchMode=”singleTask” />
```

Like this when you go launch `Activity B`, `Activity C` will get destroyed instead.

Normal stack (A->B->C->B).

singleTask stack (A->B).

You can check more about `launchMode` [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-activity-launch-mode-e0df1aa72242)

**OR**

alternatively you can just use `startActivityForResult()` in `Activity B` to open `Activity C` then send result back to `finish()` `Activity B` + 
`finish()`  `Activity C`;